# Finding sentences from a list which contains phrases stored in another list using python

Tags: python, list, nlp

I have a list of sentences which I need to check against another list containing some phrases. I have to check if each of the sentence in first list contains one of the phrases from the second list. If it has, then I need to assign a score of 1 to that sentence. If it doesn't then I need to assign a score of 0. For example:
If the list of sentences are `list_1=['a recent study found that pomegranate juice can be used to help alleviate prostate cancer','researchers have also noted that pomegranates help slow the spread of hormone-dependent cancers','this limits their ability to multiply']`
And the list of phrases are `list_2=['found that','noted that']`
Then I need to give all the sentences in list number 1 a score based on the condition that the sentences contain a phrase from the second list. If it has a phrase, then it should give a score of 1 and if it doesn't, it should give a score of 0.
For the above example, the first two sentences should get a score of 1 as they contain the phrases from the second list whereas the last sentence should get a score of 0 as it doesn't contain any phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the above problem by following code:

```
list_1=['a recent study found that pomegranate juice can be used to help alleviate prostate cancer','researchers have also noted that pomegranates help slow the spread of hormone-dependent cancers','this limits their ability to multiply']

list_2=['found that','noted that']
count_dict={}
for l in list_1:
    c=0
    for l2 in list_2:     
       if l.find(l2)!=-1:#then it is a substring
          c=1
          break           
    if c:#
       count_dict[l]=1
    else:
       count_dict[l]=0
```

In the above code `l.find(l2)` checks if `l2` is substring of `l`. If it is, then it returns a value which is not `-1`. You can also check `string.count(substring)` which should be greater than `0`.

Comment: It is working for my case. I need to take the scores from the dictionary and add it with another score to get a final score.

Comment: Can you give detail about another score?

Comment: I am actually using TextRank to find out scores from a particular list of sentences. After that I am using the above scores and adding them up to get a final score of the sentences. I have done the rest of the work. I was just stuck with the above part but it's clear now with your explanation of the code.